# Checking if iterable is empty before while loop

Tags: python-3.x, performance, for-loop, iterable, is-empty

Recently I have had to make dynamically changing lists I iterate through in the main loop. But they are empty initially, and may be empty sometimes.
Here are two cases:

```
# The first one
iterable = []
if iterable:
    for i in iterable:
        # do sth

# and the second
iterable = []
for i in iterable:
    # do sth
```

I'm wondering if there is some difference in performance of these 2 cases, or the **empty** check is already implemented in the **for** loop?

Comment: You can trivially try this yourself. Hint: `for` handles and empty sequence just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate over a *define* list variable, you do not encounter any problems, have a look:

```py
>>> iterable=[]
>>> for x in iterable:
    print(x)

>>>
```

The empty check is done automatically for you.

So, it is preferable to use the *second* code snippet in your question, because there is no *redundant* `if iterable:` code line.